# Android: Acceptance message for download / installation

Tags: android

I am new to Android App development. I have built an App. Now, I want to show an acceptance message for users to confirm for downloading and installing the app. Do I need to do anything in my app or I need to manage it at Google Play account only or Google will take care of this?

Comment: Why acceptance message ? Users will download and install on their own at google play. They will be confirmed once download completes that it's installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play handles the whole downloading and installation, you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Thanks. I also guessed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an End User License Agreement anyway, you can do that on first launch of your app.